# Yii php Paypal credit card payment integration

Tags: php, yii

I know this sounds vague, but I'm looking for a way to build a Yii paypal credit card payment methods for a credit based purchase system. Is there a good yii php library that does it? Any good resources to learn how to do it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

paypal like other payment services offer two flavours of their payment systems.

One is off site, where user is redirected to parent page from iframe(usually) that you clicked on.

The other option is integrated, where your transaction is seemlessly worked into your website so you never leave the page.

Your first step is deciding which one of these you want, the costs, the payment gateway fees your willing to deal with. If you are big enough to need a merchant account.

Comment: probably going for the simpler one first. As long as users can pay with their paypal or credit card, it will be fine

Comment: ok then a good place to start is reading their API documentation.
https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_documentation

Comment: you will need to get approved for a developers sandbox. once this is set up, become extremely comfterable with their online tools.

Answer (score 4):

Try out this extension http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/paypal/

It has PayPals Direct Payment API integration use 'DoDirectPayment' method of the component.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to have a look at these extensions
http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/tiny-paypal-shop/ 
http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/ppext/

And a forum thread related to ppext 
http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/12696-ppext-paypal-extension/ 

Tutorial 
http://alanhollis.com/yii-using-ppextbuttonmanager/

Edit: Wiki article http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/433/paypal-integration-and-ipn-instant-payment-notification/